# How am I supposed to use FluentNHibernate.Testing's CheckList properly?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to use the [persistence specification testing](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing) built into FNH.  The `CheckList` method seems to have been added recently, but the older `CheckEnumerable` has already been deprecated, so I'm assuming that `CheckList` is stable.

My test code looks similar to this:

```
new PersistenceSpecification<Parent>(session)
    .CheckProperty(x => x.Foo, 123)
    .CheckList(x => x.Children,
        new Child[] { new Child { Name = "Bob" } },
        (p, c) =>
        {
            p.Children.Add(c);
            c.Parent = p;
        })
    .VerifyTheMappings();
```

Note that in the mapping, the `Parent` owns the relationship (has `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()` and **doesn't** have `Inverse`).

When I run it, I get the dreaded *"Cannot insert NULL value into..."* SQL Server error message, because NHibernate isn't setting the `ParentId` on the `Child` entity.  Same as what happens when you forget to set up the association on both ends.

I checked with a breakpoint and the code inside the lambda isn't even getting *executed*, which is obviously why the association isn't being set properly.

The mappings themselves are totally correct; I can write ordinary code to create and insert an entity just fine.  It's just the `CheckList` method that I can't get to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note: It seems to get further if I use `CheckComponentList` instead of `CheckList`, but that's also ultimately a dead end because it lands me with the cryptic/useless error message: `Expected 'MyNamespace.MyType' but got 'MyNamespace.MyType' at position 0`.

Comment: I think I've seen this cryptic error message whenever I didn't override the Equals or GetHashCode correctly within the MyNamespace.MyType class.  You may want to debug those methods to see why the comparisons are not equal.  I'm not sure that CheckComponentList is what you need though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it appears that you do need to use `CheckComponentList` instead of `CheckList`.  I'm not sure what `CheckList` does or if it works at all right now, but I looked at the SQL trace and `CheckComponentList` was generating the correct statements.

`CheckComponentList` uses the default equality comparer unless one is explicitly specified, which is reference-equality for reference types that do not override `Equals`, so it is critical to either override `Equals` in the child entity class or use one of the `CheckComponentList` overloads that takes an `IEqualityComparer` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and my solution was to avoid setting the "back" reference (c.Parent = p). I don't know if that fixes your problem, but you can try it.

Comment: The problem here is that the back reference *isn't* being set. Removing that line doesn't change anything because the callback is never executed.